# Laravel Multiple Sessions

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

I have got the following problem. I have got an site developed in Anuglar + Laravel. We have got two types of profiles. User and Fanpage. We want the user to be able to switch between these two users like on Facebook with the normal user and his fan page.
We wanted to use multiple sessions for this. The user logs in and gets his session. when going to his fanpage he gets a new session for this fanpage. When leavin it we use the normal user session again.

We cannot find a way to use multiple sessions inside Laravel though.
Is there any way to do this?

P.S. We use Laravel 5 if this is important.

Comment: Can't you use a flag to remember that the user is currently logged in as a fanpage?

Comment: I don't think two sessions are required either. All the authentication is done through the user anyways isn't it?

Comment: yes of course it would be able to use only one session and store everything in it but it would be good if it would be possible to manage multiple sessions